# Azure Mobile Services Browser Login Dialog

Tags: azure-mobile-services

This is driving me insane and I had it working b4 but I forgot what I need to enter...After I F5 a C# Azure Mobile Service, I go to the URI using a browser and it shows me the initial test page stating "This mobile service is up and running." Clicking the "Try it out link" pops a login dialog. Where do I get these values????

Answer (score 1):

User name can be anything, password is the application key or master key from the config page in the portal.  I believe you can lock it down as well, to just master key / no access if desired, but don't remember off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

Phillipv is right, except when I first tried to do this I used usernames like "admin" or blank.  For some reason that didn't work.  I used "asd" and it did work.  That makes absolutely no sense to me with my current understanding of my set up but I just thought I would mention it in case someone else had a similar issue.